# Stagger increments in C# NumericUpDown control

Tags: c#, numericupdown

I am facing some trouble trying to configure a particular configuration for a NumericUpDown control in c#.

Basically, I have seen that I can set the Increment interval, but I would like to manage the Increment interval depending on which arrow is clicked (up or down). I have checked the events of the control, but I do not find an event for each arrow.

Basically, I want to achieve a control where, at different values, the increment is different.

from 0.00 to 5.00 increments of 0.01, from 5.00 to 20.00 increments of 0.04, and so on

Is this possible ?

Note: It would be useful also an historic value in the control for the last value when the valuechanged event is trigger. Does this exist?

Thanks in advance for any comment or suggestion!!!

EDIT: I edit this, because I did not explained it correctly, I guess. Here it is the reason because I would like to know which arrow was pressed, up or down.

This what I do have, more or less. I have added all the ranges, and some checkings using Modulo division to avoid incorrect values set directly in the value field using the keyboard instead of the arrows. The problem is, if I use arrow up to pass through a limit, everything is OK. However, if I use the arrow down, I miss one step.

```
    if (cuotaUno.Value >= 30M && cuotaUno.Value < 50M)
    {
        cuotaUno.Increment = 2M;
        if (!((cuotaUno.Value % 2M) == 0))
        {
            cuotaUno.Value = cuotaUno.Value - (cuotaUno.Value % 2M);
        }

    }

    if (cuotaUno.Value >= 50M && cuotaUno.Value < 100M)
    {
        cuotaUno.Increment = 5M;
        if (!((cuotaUno.Value % 5M) == 0))
        {
            cuotaUno.Value = cuotaUno.Value - (cuotaUno.Value % 5M);
        }

    }
```

In this case, If the value is 100 and I click down, it goes directly to 90 instead of 95. But, If I am at 90 and I click up, it goes to 95 and 100 correctly.

Comment: Why do you have to know which button was pressed?  just check the value in the NumericUpDown.ValueChanged event handler, and adjust the NumericUpDown.Increment accordingly.

Comment: You would have set the increment to 10M on reaching 100. Now when you come back it is still 10M and hence the value now becomes 90M. This also happens when you decrease value from 50. It would go to 50. This is because (50-5) is 45 and this falls in the 30 to 49 range where you've checked for divisibility by 2M and reduced 1M and hence the value is 44. Check my solution for the workaround.

Comment: Beware! Do not set cuotaUno.Value at any time while doing the logics. Just store it in a variable, do the logic with the variable and finally set it to the property. Otherwise it would again trigger the ValueChanged event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the miracle using the [NumericUpDown.ValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.valuechanged.aspx) event and [NumericUpDown.Increment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.increment.aspx) property.

As a side note, just check the [NumericUpDown.Accelerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.accelerations.aspx) property if it would help you as I don't know if you're very particular about the increment or the acceleration.

**UPDATE**

```
readonly decimal PART1 = 30M;
readonly decimal PART2 = 50M;
readonly decimal PART3 = 100M;
readonly decimal INC1 = 1M;
readonly decimal INC2 = 2M;
readonly decimal INC5 = 5M;
readonly decimal INC10 = 10M;

private void cuotaUno_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal val = cuotaUno.Value;
    decimal inc = cuotaUno.Increment;
    decimal rem;

    if (val < PART1 && inc != INC1)
    {
        if (inc == INC2 && val == (PART1 -INC2))
            val += (inc - INC1);
        inc = INC1;
    }
    else if (val >= PART1 && val < PART2 && inc != INC2)
    {
        if (inc == INC5 && val == (PART2-INC5))
            val += (inc - INC2);
        inc = INC2;
        rem = val % INC2;
        if (rem != 0)
            val -= rem;
    }
    else if (val >= PART2 && val < PART3 && inc != INC5)
    {
        if (inc == INC10 && val == (PART3-INC10))
            val += (inc - INC5);
        inc = INC5;
        rem = val % INC5;
        if (rem != 0)
            val -= rem;
    }
    else if (val >= PART3 && inc != INC10)
    {
        inc = INC10;
        rem = val % INC10;
        if (rem != 0)
            val -= rem;
    }

    cuotaUno.Increment = inc;
    cuotaUno.Value = val;            
}
```

Comment: How can I know which arrow was pressed using that event and property? I do not see it :-(

Comment: could do it yourself - on each ValueChanged, store the new value somewhere, like a decimal? instance var of your subclass, then you'll be able to tell in the event both the current and last value, which sounds like is enough (if i'm parsing things right)

Comment: Thank you Veer, I think that assigning directly the result of the calculation to the value was triggering the event again, which was opening a can of worms :-)

thank you again for your answer, it turned out extremely helpful.

Regards!

Comment: @mihe: `I think that assigning directly the result of the calculation to the value was triggering the event again, which was opening a can of worms` No! That was not the actual reason in your case. The reason is explained in my first comment to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this work?

```
private void NumericUpDown1_ValueChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if(NumericUpDown1.Value >= 0 && NumericUpDown1.Value < 5)
    {
        NumericUpDown1.Increment = 0.01;
    }
    if(NumericUpDown1.Value >= 5 && NumericUpDown1.Value < 20)
    {
        NumericUpDown1.Increment = 0.04;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your own control that inerits the NumericUpDown control.

Override the OnkeyDown method, check the current value and change the increment, then call the base class's implmentation.

That's what i would try.

Comment: Hi Bob,

first of all, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I do not see how the OnKeyDown method covers what I would like to do, since the control can be changed in several ways, so it does not solve the problem, as far as I understand.

Thanks!!